# Why is Jersey providing outdated data?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a `List` of objects in my provider class:

```
List<Workspace> workspaces = new ArrayList<Workspace>();
```

And I have a method which can provide this list of workspaces in JSON:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Workspace> workspaces() {
    return workspaces;
}
```

This does work. I have another method which updates the `List` like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Workspace> create(Workspace workspace) {
    workspaces.add(workspace);
    return workspaces;
}
```

This also works: it returns the full list of workspaces, including the one just passed in.

The problem is that when I `GET` the resource again using the first method, any new items I `POST`ed using the second method are not there. The only items I see are one which were added by the provider class's constructor. How can I persist this data?

Comment: Just a guess. (If your client is a browser) it might be caching the data from previous call. Use a t=time_in_seconds to bust the cache.

Comment: My client is a desktop application made for checking apis. I don't think it's caching anything.

Comment: May be then your POST call is operating on a different bean. Are these beans singleton? Try printing 'this' pointer in each call.

Comment: Well now it is. Could you please answer this question? This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be then your POST call is operating on a different bean. Are these beans singleton? Try printing 'this' pointer in each call.

Comment: I simply added the `@Singleton` annotation before my provider class, and that fixed the issue.